# Relationship between monogenic and conservative classical systems

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, hamiltonian-formalism

Under consideration is a classical mechanical system.

At first I would like to ask for a simple example of non-monogenic systems, e.g. something where a single or a few mass points are considered (e.g. atoms).

Secondly, do non-monogenic systems exist whose potential is not time dependent?

Thirdly, can non-monogenic systems whose potential is not time dependent still be conservative systems?

Comment: Where have you looked on the Web,  or otherwise?

Comment: I searched in the web with Google. Since Google searches also books and articles, I searched implicitly almost everything. But I do not find anything at all regarding non-monogenic systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monogenic systems are systems where the generalised potential, $U(q,\dot{q},t)$ can be expressed as a function of position, velocity and time (and nothing else). The components of generalised force are given by:
$$Q_j=-\frac{\partial U(q,\dot{q},t)}{\partial q_j}+\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial U(q,\dot{q},t)}{\partial \dot{q}_j})$$
A conservative system is a special case of mongenic systems where the generalised force is the negative gradient of the potential function. The second term of the right hand side of the above equation goes to zero.
$$Q_j=-\frac{\partial U(q,\dot{q},t)}{\partial q_j}$$
A simple example for a non-monogenic system is a system with dissipation (friction). In this case we can introduce special functions like Rayleigh's dissipation function, but these are not potentials in the usual sense, since their corresponding force cannot be given by the formulae above.

The obscurity involved in defining 'potentials' for non-monogenic systems makes it hard to say whether they can be time dependent. If you are fine with considering functions like the Rayleigh dissipation function as potentials, then sure they can be time-independent.

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time I can answer my third question.

A classical system is conservative by definition if and only if $ \vec{F} = -\nabla \Phi.$

A classical system is monogenic by definition if and only if $\mathcal{F}_i= - \frac{\partial \mathcal{V}}{\partial q_i}+\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{V}}{\partial \dot{q_i}}\right)$.

Thus by these definitions (both found in Wikipedia) a conservative system is always a special case of a monogenic system.